# Add rows in a specific column in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a table in HTML, which has 616 rows. However, I would like to add an extra column, and each of the rows for that column would contain the same element. Is there a way with JS to do that? What I would like to add on each row for that column is this symbol
Which is just an add button that goes in every element.
Here is my code:

```html
<div class="scrollingTable">
  <div class="row justify-content-center">
    <div class="col-md-8 col-lg-8 mb-8">
      <input type="text" id="myInput" onkeyup="myFunction()" placeholder="Search for names.." title="Type in a name">
      <table id="myTable" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="1" border="1" width="300">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th title="Field #1">drinkName</th>
            <th title="Field #2">drinkSizeInFlOz</th>
            <th title="Field #3">calories</th>
            <th title="Field #4">caffeineInMg</th>
            <th title="Field #5">caffeineInMgPerFloz</th>
            <th title="Field #6">type</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td>28 Black Energy Drink</td>
            <td>8.46</td>
            <td align="right">125</td>
            <td align="right">80</td>
            <td align="right">9.5</td>
            <td>ED</td>
            <td><button type="submit" id="myButton">+</button></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>3 Water </td>
            <td>16.9</td>
            <td align="right">0</td>
            <td align="right">50</td>
            <td align="right">3.0</td>
            <td>W</td>
            <td><button type="submit" id="myButton">+</button></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>3D Energy Drink</td>
            <td>16</td>
            <td align="right">15</td>
            <td align="right">200</td>
            <td align="right">12.5</td>
            <td>ED</td>
            <td><button type="submit" id="myButton">+</button></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>4 Purpose Energy Drink</td>
            <td>8.46</td>
            <td align="right">70</td>
            <td align="right">70</td>
            <td align="right">8.3</td>
            <td>ED</td>
            <td><button type="submit" id="myButton">+</button></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>4C Energy Drink Mix</td>
            <td>16.9</td>
            <td align="right">15</td>
            <td align="right">170</td>
            <td align="right">10.1</td>
            <td>ED</td>
            <td><button type="submit" id="myButton">+</button></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>5 Hour Energy</td>
            <td>1.93</td>
            <td align="right">4</td>
            <td align="right">200</td>
            <td align="right">103.6</td>
            <td>ES</td>
            <td><button type="submit" id="myButton">+</button></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>5 Hour Energy Extra Strength</td>
            <td>1.93</td>
            <td align="right">0</td>
            <td align="right">230</td>
            <td align="right">119.2</td>
            <td>ES</td>
            <td><button type="submit" id="myButton">+</button></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
```

Comment: For a button to be added, you will need to loop and insert the element[s] into the DOM. There is no quick solution.

Answer (score 1):

I created the jsfiddle for your problem.

```js
var trs = document.querySelectorAll("#myTable tbody tr");
for (var tr of trs) {
  let td = document.createElement("td");
  let btn = document.createElement("button");
  btn.innerHTML = "+";
  btn.type = "submit";
  td.appendChild(btn);
  tr.appendChild(td);
}
```

```html
<html>
<body>
<div class="scrollingTable">
                <div class="row justify-content-center">
                    <div class="col-md-8 col-lg-8 mb-8" >
                        <input type="text" id="myInput" onkeyup="myFunction()" placeholder="Search for names.." title="Type in a name" >
                        <table id="myTable" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="1" border="1" width="300">
                            <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <th title="Field #1">drinkName</th>
                                    <th title="Field #2">drinkSizeInFlOz</th>
                                    <th title="Field #3">calories</th>
                                    <th title="Field #4">caffeineInMg</th>
                                    <th title="Field #5">caffeineInMgPerFloz</th>
                                    <th title="Field #6">type</th>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>28 Black Energy Drink</td>
                                    <td>8.46</td>
                                    <td align="right">125</td>
                                    <td align="right">80</td>
                                    <td align="right">9.5</td>
                                    <td>ED</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>3 Water </td>
                                    <td>16.9</td>
                                    <td align="right">0</td>
                                    <td align="right">50</td>
                                    <td align="right">3.0</td>
                                    <td>W</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>3D Energy Drink</td>
                                    <td>16</td>
                                    <td align="right">15</td>
                                    <td align="right">200</td>
                                    <td align="right">12.5</td>
                                    <td>ED</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>4 Purpose Energy Drink</td>
                                    <td>8.46</td>
                                    <td align="right">70</td>
                                    <td align="right">70</td>
                                    <td align="right">8.3</td>
                                    <td>ED</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>4C Energy Drink Mix</td>
                                    <td>16.9</td>
                                    <td align="right">15</td>
                                    <td align="right">170</td>
                                    <td align="right">10.1</td>
                                    <td>ED</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>5 Hour Energy</td>
                                    <td>1.93</td>
                                    <td align="right">4</td>
                                    <td align="right">200</td>
                                    <td align="right">103.6</td>
                                    <td>ES</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>5 Hour Energy Extra Strength</td>
                                    <td>1.93</td>
                                    <td align="right">0</td>
                                    <td align="right">230</td>
                                    <td align="right">119.2</td>
                                    <td>ES</td>
                                </tr>
                                
                                </tbody>
                                </table>
                                </div>
                                </div>
                                </div>
                                
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: with a sufficient explaination this could have been a good answer. As of now it is a code only answer whcih is hard to understand. (unelss of course you know the solution, in whcihc ase you wouldnt need to ask in the first place).

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of ways to insert a column into each row of a table.
It all depends on what libraries you are using.
I will assume that you are using vanilla Javascript, (i.e: no external libraries).

Here is one way to insert a column, and control the content of each cell,
including detecting if you are currently on the table header, or normal cell.

```js
const btn = document.getElementById('my-button');
btn.addEventListener('click', function(){
  const tr = document.querySelectorAll('#my-table tr');
  tr.forEach((row,index) => {
    let cell;
    if(index===0) {
      cell = document.createElement('th');
      cell.innerText = "fourth column";
    } else {
      cell = document.createElement('td');
      cell.innerText = `row ${index},4`;
    }
    
    row.appendChild(cell);
  });
  
});
```

```css
table, td, th
{
border: 1px solid grey;
border-collapse: collapse;
}

td, th
{
padding: 1em;
}

button
{
margin-top: 2em;
}
```

```html
<button id="my-button">Insert missing column</button>

<table id="my-table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>first column</th>
      <th>second column</th>
      <th>third column</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>row 1, 1</td>
      <td>row 1, 2</td>
      <td>row 1, 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>row 2, 1</td>
      <td>row 2, 2</td>
      <td>row 2, 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>row 3, 1</td>
      <td>row 3, 2</td>
      <td>row 3, 3</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const rows = document.getElementsByTagName("table")[0].rows; //Get all rows

for (let i = 1; i < rows.length; i++) { // Iterate rows of body
  const row = rows[i]; // Get row
  const button = document.createElement("button"); // Create button
  button.innerHTML = "+"; // Set text of button
  const cell = document.createElement("td"); // Create column
  cell.appendChild(button); // Add button to column
  row.appendChild(cell); // Add column to row
}
```

```html
<div class="scrollingTable">
  <div class="row justify-content-center">
    <div class="col-md-8 col-lg-8 mb-8">
      <input type="text" id="myInput" onkeyup="myFunction()" placeholder="Search for names.." title="Type in a name">
      <table id="myTable" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="1" border="1" width="300">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th title="Field #1">drinkName</th>
            <th title="Field #2">drinkSizeInFlOz</th>
            <th title="Field #3">calories</th>
            <th title="Field #4">caffeineInMg</th>
            <th title="Field #5">caffeineInMgPerFloz</th>
            <th title="Field #6">type</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td>28 Black Energy Drink</td>
            <td>8.46</td>
            <td align="right">125</td>
            <td align="right">80</td>
            <td align="right">9.5</td>
            <td>ED</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>3 Water </td>
            <td>16.9</td>
            <td align="right">0</td>
            <td align="right">50</td>
            <td align="right">3.0</td>
            <td>W</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>3D Energy Drink</td>
            <td>16</td>
            <td align="right">15</td>
            <td align="right">200</td>
            <td align="right">12.5</td>
            <td>ED</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>4 Purpose Energy Drink</td>
            <td>8.46</td>
            <td align="right">70</td>
            <td align="right">70</td>
            <td align="right">8.3</td>
            <td>ED</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>4C Energy Drink Mix</td>
            <td>16.9</td>
            <td align="right">15</td>
            <td align="right">170</td>
            <td align="right">10.1</td>
            <td>ED</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>5 Hour Energy</td>
            <td>1.93</td>
            <td align="right">4</td>
            <td align="right">200</td>
            <td align="right">103.6</td>
            <td>ES</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>5 Hour Energy Extra Strength</td>
            <td>1.93</td>
            <td align="right">0</td>
            <td align="right">230</td>
            <td align="right">119.2</td>
            <td>ES</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

## IMPORTANT!

### #IDs ARE UNIQUE!

**Do not have more than one of the same #id on a page because it's:**

- invalid HTML
- semantically gross
- behavior becomes unpredictable
- JavaScript if not immediately but eventually break
- the terrorists win

There's like a ton of these in OP:

```html
<button type="submit" id="myButton">+</button> <!---->
```

Try to avoid using `#id` at all -- use `.class` instead.
In the example below the function `insertCol()` is versatile and reusable. The `<table>` has a `<tfoot>` for demonstration purposes. Details are commented in the example.

```js
// This object stores content for insertCol() to fill a table
let content = {
  cap: {
    text: 'TEXT',
    side: '',
    act: 0 // 1='use data' 0='skip data'
  },
  tH: {
    th: 'tH',
    act: 0
  },
  tB: {
    th: '',
    td: `<td><button class="btn btn-sm btn-info add">➕</button></td>`,
    act: 1
  },
  tF: {
    td: 'tF',
    act: 0
  }
};

/**
 * @desc - Inserts a column into a given table
 * @param {number} index - Index to inert new column at
 * @param {object} content - Object that stores content
 * @param {string<selector>} selector - CSS Selector of a 
 *        tag if undefined @default is "table"
 */
function insertCol(index, content, selector = 'table') {
  // Reference <table>
  const table = document.querySelector(selector);
  // Collect all <tr> into an array
  const rowArray = [...table.rows];
  let cols = rowArray[0].cells.length;
  let size = rowArray.length;
  //console.log(size);
  //console.log(cols);

  /*
  If content.tB is active (1)...
  ... .foreach() <tr> add <td> and content at the index
  */
  if (content.tB.act) {
    rowArray.forEach(tr => {
      tr.insertCell(index).innerHTML = content.tB.td;
    });
  }
  /*
  If there's a <thead> AND content.tH.act === 1...
  ... .removeCell() at index...
  ... add <th> with content
  */
  if (table.tHead && content.tH.act) {
    rowArray[0].deleteCell(index);
    rowArray[0].insertCell(index).outerHTML = `<th>${content.tH.th}</th>`;
  }
  // The same as above for <tfoot>
  if (table.tFoot && content.tF.act) {
    rowArray[size - 1].deleteCell(index);
    rowArray[size - 1].insertCell(index).innerHTML = content.tF.td;
  }
  // This block is for <caption>
  if (table.caption && content.cap.act) {
    table.caption.innerHTML = content.cap.text;
    table.caption.style.captionSide = content.cap.side;
  }
}

// -1 is the index after the last index
insertCol(-1, content);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title></title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <style></style>
</head>

<body>
  <main class="container scrollingTable">
    <section class="row justify-content-center">
      <div class="col-md-8 col-lg-8 mb-8">
        <label class='form-label' for='search'>Search</label>
        <input id="search" class='form-control mb-2' type="text" placeholder="Search for names..">
        <table class='table table-striped table-hover'>
          <caption></caption>
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th title="Field #1">drinkName</th>
              <th title="Field #2">drinkSizeInFlOz</th>
              <th title="Field #3">calories</th>
              <th title="Field #4">caffeineInMg</th>
              <th title="Field #5">caffeineInMgPerFloz</th>
              <th title="Field #6">type</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td>28 Black Energy Drink</td>
              <td>8.46</td>
              <td>125</td>
              <td>80</td>
              <td>9.5</td>
              <td>ED</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>3 Water </td>
              <td>16.9</td>
              <td>0</td>
              <td>50</td>
              <td>3.0</td>
              <td>W</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>3D Energy Drink</td>
              <td>16</td>
              <td>15</td>
              <td>200</td>
              <td>12.5</td>
              <td>ED</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>4 Purpose Energy Drink</td>
              <td>8.46</td>
              <td>70</td>
              <td>70</td>
              <td>8.3</td>
              <td>ED</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>4C Energy Drink Mix</td>
              <td>16.9</td>
              <td>15</td>
              <td>170</td>
              <td>10.1</td>
              <td>ED</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>5 Hour Energy</td>
              <td>1.93</td>
              <td>4</td>
              <td>200</td>
              <td>103.6</td>
              <td>ES</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>5 Hour Energy Extra Strength</td>
              <td>1.93</td>
              <td>0</td>
              <td>230</td>
              <td>119.2</td>
              <td>ES</td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
          <tfoot>
            <tr>
              <td>FOOT</td>
              <td>FOOT</td>
              <td>FOOT</td>
              <td>FOOT</td>
              <td>FOOT</td>
              <td>FOOT</td>
            </tr>
          </tfoot>
        </table>
      </div>
    </section>
  </main>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
  <script></script>
</body>

</html>
```